# Update model property in code first approch

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am not able to update any property name or DataAnnotations for any property.

Here code

**Class**:

```
public class Student
{
     public Student()
     {

     }
     [Key]
     public int StudentID { get; set; }
     public string StudentName { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
     public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
     public decimal Height { get; set; }
     public float Weight { get; set; }
     public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}
```

**Context**

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext 
{
     public SchoolContext()
      : base("name=SchoolDBConnectionString")
     {

     }

     public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }
}
```

Now I want to update StudentName as required field

I am trying with below code
Update class-> Student

```
[Required]
 public string StudentName { get; set; }
```

And Context Class(OnModelCreating)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasRequired(p => p.StudentName);
```

When I was run this program then I got error :

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
Additional information: The model backing the 'SchoolContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database.*

If I delete database and run this program then working fine. But I don't want delete database on change in property.

Can you please give information. How can I update model property?

Comment: You can use migrations, please refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801545/Code-First-Migrations-With-Entity-Framework

Comment: I have run CM>Update-Database -Verbose then got error :Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss. Set AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed to 'true' on your DbMigrationsConfiguration to allow application of automatic migrations even if they might cause data loss. Alternately, use Update-Database with the '-Force' option, or scaffold an explicit migration. 

After CM>Update-Database -Force  then working fine